# How to switch between split panes in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

This seems like a simple task but I can't seem to track down an answer.

In JetBrains' PHPStorm, what is the shortcut for switching between split panes?  (Using OS X)

[image: PHP Storm split pane example]

Comment: Tab shift https://github.com/dkandalov/tab-shift is a handy plugin to make this more extensible.

Comment: `Ctrl+Tab` (and Mac equivalent) is for switching between **recently used tabs** -- it will switch within the same splitter if recent tab was from the same splitter. Therefore it will not work in ALL situations.

Comment: @LazyOne a ha. You’re right. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

- **Window | Editor Tabs | Goto Next Splitter**
- **Window | Editor Tabs | Goto Previous Splitter**

Keyboard shortcuts can be changed at `Preferences | Keymap`

Answer (score 64):

The default for "Go to next splitter" for Mac users is <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: And for Windows, it's Ctrl+Tab.

Comment: Much better! Thanks!